# Need video player for ASP.NET(Should Support IE 7.0 + all browser)

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming, html5-video

I need to implement a video player that should play files(wmv, mpeg, mp4 etc..), I have tried object tag, but it requires media player plugin to play I dont want this kind. Somebody can suggest me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For playing Video in Website, the users need to download plugin (WMP or any other player). Without the plugin, Video cannot stream or play in browser.